# can this java calculator program be more simplified?

Tags: java, code-cleanup

Im a beginner in java, this is a simple calculator code which i made with the help of a tutorial. This works just fine, but as you can see their is no "constructor" in this program! And their is only a scanner object!
Can this program be more simplified in a way it has contructors and methods, as an example for me to learn ?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class apples {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner calculator = new Scanner(System.in);
    double fnum, snum, answer;

    System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
    fnum = calculator.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
    snum = calculator.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("enter any operator: ");
    String op = calculator.next();
    switch (op){
    case ("x") :
        answer = fnum * snum;
        System.out.println(answer);
        break;

    case ("/") :
        answer = fnum / snum;
    System.out.println(answer);
    break;

    case ("+") :
        answer = fnum + snum;
    System.out.println(answer);
    break;

    case ("-") :
        answer = fnum - snum;
    System.out.println(answer);
    break;


    }

    }





}
```

Comment: simplified means performance wise or easy to read?

Comment: move it to [codereview.se] please.

Comment: why is the class name `apples` ? you are making a calculator right? make a habit of using meaningful names

Comment: Having no constructor is not a bad thing, on the contrary.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This code is, if anything, already overly simplistic. So no, there's little point in trying to simplify it further. You **could** move the `System.out.println` to below the `switch`, that would save you three lines of repeated code.

Comment: @Marko I think the real question here is how to make it an exercise of object oriented programming; which is valid for [codereview.se].

Comment: @codesparkle Without more requirements on the program, the OOP-ized solution will only acquire pointless complexity. Many times I found myself staring at a completely unmotivated piece of code in a book, wondering why one would write such a monstrosity when clearly much simpler solutions work. The sense of tension and release is key to good education, but achieving it is no trifling matter.

Comment: @ marko .. yes you are rite, i want to learn .. about objects, constructors and methods with examples ...
But with the above example as you can see ... that there are no constructors or methods .... just wanted some example as simple as the calculator program to learn.

Comment: @codesparkle This is not sharpedge's question. He is just trolling :)

Comment: Guys im completely new to forums , i heard that guys like you can help us newbies learn :)
If u can give me an example ... easy for me to understand or change my code adding constructors and methods, it would really be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

One idea could be use more functional style to reduce redundant operator and ugly case switches and make code more maintain-friendly:

```
import java.util.*;
public class apples {
    protected static final Map<String, BinOp> operators = new HashMap<String, BinOp>() {{
        put("+", new BinOp() { public double calc(double op1, double op2) { return op1 + op2; }; });
        put("-", new BinOp() { public double calc(double op1, double op2) { return op1 - op2; }; });
        put("x", new BinOp() { public double calc(double op1, double op2) { return op1 * op2; }; });
        put("/", new BinOp() { public double calc(double op1, double op2) { return op1 / op2; }; });
    }};
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner calculator = new Scanner(System.in);
        double fnum, snum, answer;

        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        fnum = calculator.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        snum = calculator.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("enter any operator: ");
        String op = calculator.next();
        BinOp opFunction = operators.get(op);
        answer = opFunction.calc(fnum, snum);
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}

interface BinOp {
    double calc(double op1, double op2);
}
```

Of course, you should handle not double values in input or non existent operators.

Another good idea is to separate logic:

```
import java.util.*;
public class apples {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner calculator = new Scanner(System.in);
        double fnum, snum, answer;

        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        fnum = calculator.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        snum = calculator.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("enter any operator: ");
        String op = calculator.next();
        answer = calc(op, fnum, snum);
        System.out.println(answer);
    }

    public static double calc(String op, double op1, double op2) {
        switch (op) {
            case ("+"): return op1 + op2;
            case ("-"): return op1 - op2;
            case ("x"): return op1 * op2;
            case ("/"): return op1 / op2;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented!");
    }
}
```

It make your code more readable and also maintainable.

And because I really like enums:

```
import java.util.*;
public class apples {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner calculator = new Scanner(System.in);
        double fnum, snum, answer;

        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        fnum = calculator.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        snum = calculator.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("enter any operator: ");
        String op = calculator.next();
        Operation operator = Operation.get(op);
        answer = operator.calc(fnum, snum);
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}

enum Operation {
    ADD("+") {
        public double calc(double op1, double op2) {
            return op1 + op2;
        }
    },
    SUB("-") {
        public double calc(double op1, double op2) {
            return op1 - op2;
        }
    },
    MUL("x") {
        public double calc(double op1, double op2) {
            return op1 * op2;
        }
    },
    DIV("/") {
        public double calc(double op1, double op2) {
            return op1 / op2;
        }   
    },
    ;

    Operation(String op) {
        this.op = op;
    }
    protected String op;
    public abstract double calc(double op1, double op2);
    public static Operation get(String op) {
        for (Operation operation : values()) {
            if (operation.op.equals(op)) {
                return operation;
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented!");
    }
}
```

You can use also on other places as:

```
answer = Operation.MUL(2, 3);
```

and easy iterate over all operations, get names etc.

Comment: i like the logic, the maintainable code :)
Thanks ... but i haven't yet learned about "enum" .. :(

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED---------------------------------**

Here's my solution ;):

The launcher(may be from servlet also for instance, whatever you want):

```
  public class Launcher {

    private final Scanner scanner;

    public Launcher(Scanner scanner) {
        this.scanner = scanner;
    }

    public Scanner getScanner() {
        return scanner;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Launcher launcher = new Launcher(new Scanner(System.in));
        launcher.printResult(launcher.takeOperandInput("first"), launcher.takeOperandInput("second"),
                launcher.takeOperatorInput());
    }

    private String takeOperandInput(String operandNumber) {
        askForOperand(operandNumber);
        return getElement();
    }

    private void askForOperand(String operand) {
        System.out.println("Enter " + operand + " :");
    }

    private String takeOperatorInput() {
        askForOperator();
        return getElement();
    }

    private void askForOperator() {
        System.out.println("enter any operator (+,-,/,*): ");
    }

    private String getElement() {
        return scanner.next();
    }

    private void printResult(String leftOperand, String rightOperand, String operator) {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator(leftOperand, rightOperand, operator);
        System.out.println(calculator.calculate());
    }
}
```

Here the `Calculator` class:

```
public class Calculator {

    private final Operands operands;

    private final OperationType operationType;

    public Calculator(String leftOperand, String rightOperand, String operationType) {
        this.operands = new Operands(leftOperand,  rightOperand);
        this.operationType = OperationType.transform(operationType);;
    }

    public double calculate() {
        return operationType.calculate(operands);
    }
}
```

Here the immutable `Operands` class:

```
final class Operands {

    private final double leftOperand;

    private final double rightOperand;

    public Operands(String leftOperand, String rightOperand) {
        this.leftOperand = Double.parseDouble(leftOperand);
        this.rightOperand = Double.parseDouble(rightOperand);
    }

    public final double getLeftOperand() {
        return leftOperand;
    }

    public final double getRightOperand() {
        return rightOperand;
    }
}
```

Here the `OperationType` enum containing logic:

```
enum OperationType {

    ADDITION("+") {
        public double calculate(Operands operands) {
            return operands.getLeftOperand() + operands.getRightOperand();
        }
    },
    SUBTRACTION("-") {
        public double calculate(Operands operands) {
            return operands.getLeftOperand() - operands.getRightOperand();
        }
    },
    MULTIPLICATION("*") {
        public double calculate(Operands operands) {
            return operands.getLeftOperand() * operands.getRightOperand();
        }
    },
    DIVISION("/") {
        public double calculate(Operands operands) {
            return operands.getLeftOperand() / operands.getRightOperand();
        }
    };

    private String operationType;

    private OperationType(String operationType) {
        this.operationType = operationType;
    }

    abstract double calculate(Operands operands);

    static OperationType transform(String operationType) {
        for (OperationType ot : values()) {
            if (ot.operationType.equals(operationType)) {
                return ot;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown operator, please redo your operation.");
    }
}
```

Comment: In your example, if you add new operation, you touch 2 places: transform and calculate. Enums are more as simple value holders, see my example :). Another thing is to combine getElement, askForOperand and askForOperator into one function, for instance getElement(scanner : Scanner, askuser : String) : String because your Calculator constructor get 3 strings.

Comment: @Anton Bessonov Yes, you're right:) I haven't followed the Open/Closed principle in this little case :( Enum is likely to look like as an abstraction as interfaces are. In this case, OperationType would (or rather should) instigate a well-implemented Strategy Pattern. So that, when a new operator has to come, no need to touch to the calculator class but solely to OperationType enum.

Comment: @Anton Bessonov I've just updated my code ;)